# how to verify if a field is empty in views field template?

Tags: views, theming

I have a views row template (views-view-fields--mymodule.tpl.php)

I wanted to verify if a specific field is empty.

Is there any way to perform this ?.

Here is what I already tried.

Every try failed.

1 try

> if($field["field_fax"]){

2 try

> if(isset($fields["field_fax"]->raw)) {

3 try

> if (!is_null($fields['field_fax']->content['fid']) ) {

Thanks a lot

Comment: two things: is the first attempt just a typo, it reads $field instead of $fields, and are you sure the template file is actually running?

Comment: I even try with $fields and it's not working.

Comment: does the template file actually run?

Comment: Yeah. The template is running fine.

Comment: next I would try dpm from DEVEL module to make sure the array structure is correct. another thing to try might be a print_r($field['field_fax']);  just to see what it outputs